# Getting the dimensions of the image in ruby

Tags: ruby

To get the image dimensions in ruby, I tried to use identify to get image dimensions. I wanted to retrieve the output of this system call and get the output as a string

```
str = system('identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" image.png')
output = `ls`
print output
```

But, I'm getting the last lines of output and not the output to this particular system call. 
Also, if there is a simpler way to get the image dimensions without external gems or libraries, please suggest as it would be great !

Comment: Just wanted to check what the system call returned. So, I stored it in str . The call retuned true as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already use an external library (ImageMagick), you could use its Ruby wrapper [RMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/):

```
require 'RMagick'

img = Magick::Image::read('image.png').first
arr = [img.columns, img.rows]
```

Here's an example of a very simple PNG parser:

```
data = File.binread('image.png', 100) # read first 100 bytes

if data[0, 8] == [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10].pack("C*")
  # file has a PNG file signature, let's get the image header chunk

  length, chunk_type = data[8, 8].unpack("l>a4")

  raise "unknown format, expecting image header" unless chunk_type == "IHDR"

  chunk_data = data[16, length].unpack("l>l>CCCCC")
  width              = chunk_data[0]
  height             = chunk_data[1]
  bit_depth          = chunk_data[2]
  color_type         = chunk_data[3]
  compression_method = chunk_data[4]
  filter_method      = chunk_data[5]
  interlace_method   = chunk_data[6]

  puts "image size: #{width}x#{height}"
else
  # handle other formats
end
```

Comment: Okay, is there a solution which is possible without any external libraries ?

Comment: @actor_vijay you could write your own image parser

Comment: @actor_vijay I've update my answer, but that's just an very basic example, don't use it in production :-)

Comment: Wow ! That's an awesome answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found a solution after some experiments.

```
str = `identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" image.png`
arr = str.split('x')
```

The array arr now contains dimensions in it [width,height] .

This worked for me ! Please suggest other approaches that might be more easier or simpler.